# Linux network driver and mtu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing some network device driver for Linux. For some reasons I have to reduce dynamically MTU for my network interface while initializing.

When the driver calculates and sets MTU to for example value 892 - kernel trims outgoing frames to 310 bytes.

The question is: why the outgoing packets are 310 bytes long instead of 892 bytes?

Edit: (part of code calculating MTU)

```
bitrate = 250;  // [kbit/s]
limit_us = upstream_timeslot = 5000; // [us]
mtu = (limit_us - 144) * bitrate * 2 / 15625 - fp->wdev->hard_header_len - sizeof(struct ether_header);
```

It just calculates what is maximum value of 1 frame that fits transmission timeslot for slow transmission 250kbps.

Comment: Can you share the part of a code as how you are implementing it ? Can you elaborate little more.

Comment: Look at edit part of my question, but I'm not sure if it tells anything valuable.

Comment: Can you share your entire code. I will like to run it and conclude because this piece of code that you have shared is not giving the required insight into the issue you are facing.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not allowed to publish the code and it runs on specific hardware. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Its fine. I fancy that you are playing with the SKB structure. And if so you must be aware about "skb_put","skb_trim" and all other such functions available in Linux Kernel.